# Zombies error w ABAddressBookCreate

Tags: iphone

I see this Zombies issue on the simulator and device:

- [Not A Type class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5bf9450

The code that generates this problem could not be any more simple.

```
+ (void) testAllocateAndDeallocteAddressBook
{
  ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();

  NSAssert(addressBookRef != NULL, @"ABAddressBookCreate() returned NULL");

  CFRelease(addressBookRef);

  return;
}
```

What I do not understand is why this CFRelease() causes this error. All the Apple docs I have read about this URL indicate that CFRelease() should be invoked to release the ref.

Comment: ABAddressBookCreate is deprecated as far as I know. see here. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html   This may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the problem here. This is from the discussion on apples page.

Changes made to the returned address book are reflected in the Address Book database 
only after saving the address book with ABAddressBookSave.

On iOS 6.0 and later, if the caller does not have access to the Address Book database:

**For apps linked against iOS 6.0 and later, this function returns NULL.**
For apps linked against previous version of iOS, this function returns an 
empty read-only database.